# Interactive map in svg is not getting responsive

Tags: javascript, svg

I have develop a interactive map in `SVG` with on click event,I have also tried to make it responsive ,even though it seems responsive,but still full responsiveness of the whole thing is not coming. may b I am missing some thing here is my work

Comment: Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8zg2y7ny/

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: "still full responsiveness of the whole thing is not coming" this made no sense at all. What EXACTLY are you not able to achieve?

Comment: use this fiddle for the responsive svg map : https://codepen.io/andreawetzel/pen/avpENm

Comment: I meant to say that the box that appear when click different region seems to be not responsive in most of the device..